# TLF text is preventing onMouseOver event

Tags: flash, rollover, flash-cs5, tlf

Basically I have some TLF text as a symbol, it's read only, the font is embedded and I set mouseEnabled to false. It's sitting as a graphic, on top of a button. When I mouse over the text, or the area where the text would be, it prevents the button from receiving the on mouse over event. Using classic, dynamic text, this route normally works just fine. Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Comment: If it sounds like it's setup weird that's because it's a template setup for novices to easily edit from the library panel. Re-structuring it isn't really an option. I need to find a way to fix this with code.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the perfect hack. My button plays sounds and stuff when rolling over. So on the roll out event, I prevent it from happening like so: `function buttonOut (event:MouseEvent):void
{
 var btn:MovieClip = event.currentTarget;
 //added so that when rolling over the text
 if(!btn.getBounds(stage).contains(event.stageX, event.stageY)){
  btn.gotoAndStop("up");
 }
}` which seems to clear up my problems. Still hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to debug without the .fla but see whether maybe mouseChildren=false will work in addition to mouseEnabled=false if the TLF text is inside a movieclip or similar... if it doesn't, it could be a bug...

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren

http://ted.onflash.org/2008/12/mousechildrenfalse.php

Comment: Dude, you're so awesome, the mouseChildren=false was exactly what i needed. I can't believe I missed that in the live docs.